# Automatically run a select statement against a remote mysql server over SH tunnel every 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh, cron

I have a remote mysql server that I need to automatically select data from and insert in a local sql server database every 1 hour(Sort of a cron job). The remote mysql server can only be accessed via a SSH tunnel. Ive tried setting up a link server using mysql db connector but this link servers does not have ssh setup included.. Does anybody have an idea how this be achived

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a quick reference](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/) of how cron works. You can run MySQL script thru `.php`.

To run it every one hour, you should do it like this:

`* */01 * * * username /var/www/html/[phpFileYouWantToRun]`

You can either include /usr/bin/php in the command to run, or you can make the php scripts directly executable:

```
chmod +x file.php
```

Start your php file with a shebang so that your shell knows which interpreter to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// your code here
```

Another solution is to make an scheduled jobs in MySQL directly like in this link: "[How to Create Scheduled Events in MySQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)"

Comment: the problemis not the cronpart the problemis thatu need toautomatically insert the values in an sql server db andthe remote server can only be accessed over an encrypted tunne;.. This means u neeed to programmatically set up an ssh connection and use theconnection in selecting values for insert and programmatically perform the insert.

Comment: so you mean to duplicate or synchronize the data?.